# Laravel upload a file to different storage outside the project directory

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I'm creating a CMS wherein I can upload files(photos, pdf, etc) using Laravel's file upload. What I'm doing differently is that I want to store the file outside my CMS project directory let's say my website's storage folder. BTW I'm creating two different projects

Laravel documentation says that I can change the path where it will be uploaded in the filesystems.php what I did is get the relative path of my website storage folder and paste it here(see below).

```
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local', //here
        'root' => storage_path('app'), 
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

As expected it's not working. Any help guys?

Comment: what do you mean by outside the project directory ?

Comment: any error message?

Comment: @EmtiazZahid What I mean by that is I want to upload the file outside my CMS directory because I'm creating two separate projects. I know that by default Laravel stored the files uploaded in the project storage folder but I don't want to use that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can add multiple disk in your file system.

Just locate on same website storage folder

**Example:**

*Project 1:*

```
'disks' => [
        'custom_folder_1' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root'   => '../path/to/your/new/storage/folder',
        ],
]
```

*Project 2:*

```
'disks' => [
        'custom_folder_2' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root'   => '../path/to/your/new/storage/folder',
        ],
]
```

the path should be the same location.

```
../path/to/your/new/storage/folder
```

and then you can use it like:

```
Storage::disk('custom_folder_1')->put('filename1', $file_content);
Storage::disk('custom_folder_2')->put('filename2', $file_content);
```

Comment: I think I'd missed that in Laravel's documentation I didnt know you can create your custom storage path. Thanks men Imma try your suggestion.

Comment: Bro you save me a lot of trouble today thank you! I Upvote and accepted your answer

Comment: InvalidArgumentException with message 'Driver [custom] is not supported.'

Comment: @Eboubaker this was just an example purpose. now updated with local driver