# laravel 6 define path

Tags: php, laravel

I use the Laravel 6 for the project
I need to storage photo, I need to have a variable global with the path to make easy for change after

the path will stay outside the project directory
ex:

```
define('IMAGES_PATH','c:/storage/image')
```

and what's the best file I can make this path
.env

or Laravel have something with artisan? and how I use inside the controller

Comment: Do you plan to store the file in one of the folders in Laravels root folder or somewhere else on your drive?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57156204/laravel-upload-a-file-to-different-storage-outside-the-project-directory